# Write a trigger that automatically copy email of contact when edited to custom email fiels on custom account tab

Tags: trigger

This is how i am approaching to trigger

```
trigger UpdateAccountEmails on Contact (after update){  
    //extract all contact Ids for use in query
    contact all_contact = [select id,name,email from contact];
    Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Contact c : Trigger.new){
        if(trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Email != c.Email){//email has been changed
            contactIds.add(c.Id);
        }
    }

    List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
    for(Contact c : [SELECT Id, Account.Id, Account.Custom_Email__c FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :contactIds]){
        //assign the new email
        c.recordPageCont.Custom_Email__c = Trigger.newMap.get(c.Id).Email;
        //extract the account into our list
        accounts.add(c.getSobject('Account'));
    }

    update accounts;
}
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Can you please refer to this - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/78162/how-can-i-write-a-trigger-so-that-emailid-of-contact-get-copied-to-email-field-o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Account has many Contacts so there is a logical problem: the Account will just show the email from the last Contact updated.

But accepting that, this trigger should do the job:

```
trigger UpdateAccountEmails on Contact (after update) {
    Map<Id, Account> m = new Map<Id, Account>();
    for(Contact c : Trigger.new){
        if (Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Email != c.Email) {
            m.put(c.AccountId, new Account(Id = c.AccountId, Custom_Email__c = c.Email));
        }
    }
    update m.values();
}
```

Using the map ensures that only one Account update is done even if many Contacts from the same Account are being updated.

When updating an object that you already have an ID for there is no need to query (unless you want to also check if there is a change to the value).

Comment: Thanks a lot..Its working..But i have a question..where did you got to know about c.accountId??

Comment: @AnkitaSingh Diagrams like https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_majors.htm include it. You can also see all fields in the Setup UI and pretty much any of the development tools.

Answer (score 0):

Contacts will be updated for many reasons, not just for email address changes. Your trigger needs to be aware of that and only fire when the email address has changed. You also don't want to be querying ALL email addresses for ALL of your contacts, only the ones that have changed.

However, as you'll see, you don't even need to run that query because trigger.old will contain the previous email address making it unnecessary. Your trigger should look more like the following:

```
trigger UpdateAccountEmails on Contact (after update){  

set<contact>con2up = new set<contact>();
map<Id,string>con2eml = new map<Id,string>();
map<Id,Id>acct2con = new map<Id,Id>();

for(contact con:trigger.new)

   if(con.email != trigger.oldmap.get(con.Id).email){

      con2up.add(con.Id);
      con2eml.put(con.Id, string.valueOf(con.email));
      acct2con.put(con.accountId,conId);
   }
 }


  list<Account>accts2up = new List<Account>();

  //One would be tempted to run the following query:

  // map<Id,Account>acctsMap = new map([SELECT Id, Account.Custom_Email__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN :con2up]);
  // however, it's not needed because we already have the account Id's

  set<Id>acctIds=acct2con.keyset;

  for(Id ac:acctIds){
     account a = new account(Id=ac);
     //assign the new email
     a.Custom_Email__c = con2eml.get(acct2con.get(ac));       
     //add to list
     accts2up.add(a);
  }

   if(accts2up.isEmpty == false) update accts2up;
}
```

Comment: i am getting a following error at list<Account>accts2up = new List<Account>();

error is - Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: list at line 18 column 4

Comment: it was a typo error..i removed the curly brace ..now it is giving me another error - Compile Error: Variable does not exist: string.valueOf.con.email at line 13 column 27

Comment: i changed it to con2eml.put(con.id,con.email);
but now its giving me another error at con2up.add(con.Id); Errror is - Compile Error: Incompatible element type Id for collection of Contact at line 12 column 7

Comment: The bracket cannot be removed. I've restored the bracket. Without it, the for loop on acctIds runs once for each time through the for loop. I neglected to put parens around `con.email` in this line: `con2eml.put(con.Id, string.valueOf(con.email))` which should fix any problems with the code. `email` is not a string, that is what the message is telling you. Without the parens, it wasn't converting it to a string properly. Were you not satisfied with @KeithC answer since you marked it as the solution?

Comment: I am satisfied with the @keithc answer...i had to create a custom field on account onject  and then bind it on VF page